# IIS7 ASP.NET in-proc session NOT being lost after app recycle

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7, session-state

I've got an ASP.NET MVC app running under IIS7. It's using the default in-proc session management, which, according to all that I read, should lose the users' session after an app pool recycle.
It doesn't seem to be losing it though. Even an IIS reset doesn't lose the session. 
Has something changed in IIS7 that keeps the session alive?

Comment: Are you definitely seeing the same session data after a recycle, or just the same session ID?

Comment: Can you supply your session configuration section from your web.config?  Sounds like you're using a state server or sql server instead of the default in-proc server.

Comment: @stevemegson. Possibly just the session ID. It's possible that I'm misunderstanding how the session data is stored. The user is still logged in after an app recycle, but I'm not storing any other data in the session. 
A user should be logged out though, shouldn't they, as the server should lose its session IDs?

Comment: @D Hoerster

Here is is, nice and simple:
`<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieName="mycookie"  cookieless="false" timeout="60" />`

Comment: @Fibble:  Place something in session, response.write it to the page, recycle your app and see if the value returns back out again or if you get a null reference exception as another test.  It may be something in the way logins are handled on IIS 7 - honestly don't know, but I would try the above out of curiosity.  PS - make sure you are not setting that value in page_load of your current page (and then see that it is still there).  That's bit me before on something similar.  Also, could your login cookies have anything to do with staying logged in during an app cycle?

Comment: @Tommy, et al. When I place something in the session, it gets lost during an app recycle, as we would expect. I still can't figure out why the user is not logged out though.

Comment: the user is not logged out due to cookies.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to cookie replay - what happens is that your browser sends the cookie with old authentication ticket which is accepted as a new session as the Web server does not store valid and expired authentication tickets for later comparison. This makes your site vulnerable to a replay attack if a malicious user obtains a valid forms authentication cookie. To improve security when using a forms authentication cookie see MSDN link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx

> To improve security when using a forms authentication cookie, you
> should do the following:
>
> - Use absolute expiration for forms authentication cookies by setting the `SlidingExpiration` property to false. This limits the window in
>   which a hijacked cookie can be replayed.
> - Only issue and accept authentication cookies over Secure Sockets Layer (SSL), by setting the `RequireSSL` property to true and by
>   running the entire Web site under SSL. Setting the RequireSSL property
>   to true ensures that ASP.NET will never send an authentication cookie
>   to the browser over a non-SSL connection; however, the client might
>   not honor the secure setting on the cookie. This means the client
>   might send the forms authentication cookie over a non-SSL connection,
>   thus leaving it vulnerable to hijack. You can prevent a client from
>   sending the forms authentication cookie in the clear by running the
>   entire Web site under SSL.
> - Use persistent storage on the server to record when a user logs out of the Web site, and then use an application event such as
>   `PostAuthenticateRequest` event to determine whether the current user
>   was authenticated with forms authentication. If the user was
>   authenticated with forms authentication, and if the information in
>   persistent storage indicates the user is logged out, immediately clear
>   the authentication cookie and redirect the browser back to the login
>   page. After a successful login, update storage to reflect that the
>   user is logged in. When you use this method, your application must
>   track the logged-in status of the user, and must force idle users to
>   log out.
>
> (.NET Framework   1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6,
> 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8, 4.8.1)